# Is there a way to convert Objective-C CATransition animation into Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, uiview, migration

I'm working on outdated & unfinished project with migrating Objective-C code to Swift.
Trying to recreate UIView+stateTransition .h and .m files into Swift without any luck yet. If somebody has encountered something similar, any help of how the Objective-C code below would look in Swift format would be much appreciated.

```
//Code in UIView+stateTransition header file:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface UIView (stateTransition)

- (CATransition *)makeStandardStateTransition;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

```
//Code in UIView+stateTransition implementation file:

#import "UIView+stateTransition.h"


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@implementation UIView (stateTransition)

- (CATransition *)makeStandardStateTransition
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.12;//based on testing
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    return transition;
}

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swift equivalent of this code would look like that:

```
extension UIView {

    func makeStandardStateTransition() -> CATransition {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.12
        transition.type = .fade
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        return transition
    }

}
```